# Is it reasonable to consider the set $\bigcap_{j \geq 2} A_j$ as the limit of $A_n$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am learning this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#Monotone_sequences), which uses `sequence of sets` in the definition

> Suppose that ${\displaystyle \{A_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty }}$ is a sequence
>   of sets. The two equivalent definitions are as follows.
>
> Using union and intersection, define
>
> $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j$
>
> ...
>
> Similarly, if ${A_n}$ is nondecreasing then
>
> ${\displaystyle \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }A_{n}=\bigcup _{j\geq
>  1}A_{j}}$

To illustrate this, I am trying to find a concrete example.

let $(A_n)_{n=2}^\infty$ denote the sequence of sets $A_n$

where $A_n$ is the set of primes $\le n (n\ge 2)$.

$A_2=\{2\},\ A_3=\{2,3\},A_4=A_3,A_5=\{2,3,5\},...$

Is it reasonable to consider the set $\bigcap_{j \geq 2} A_j$ as the limit of $A_n$?

the arguable point is $n \geq 2$ other than $n \geq 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Since your sequence is non-decreasing, its limit is the union of all $A_n$'s, which is the set of all prime numbers.