# How can get the limit infimum and limit supremum of the sequence $(A_n)_{n=2}^\infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am learning this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#Monotone_sequences), which uses `sequence of sets` in the definition

> Suppose that ${\displaystyle \{A_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty }}$ is a sequence
>   of sets. The two equivalent definitions are as follows.
>
> Using union and intersection, define
>
> $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j$
>
> ...
>
> Similarly, if ${A_n}$ is nondecreasing then
>
> ${\displaystyle \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }A_{n}=\bigcup _{j\geq
>  1}A_{j}}$

To illustrate this, I am trying to find a concrete example.

let $(A_n)_{n=2}^\infty$ denote the sequence of sets $A_n$

where $A_n$ is the set of primes $\le n (n\ge 2)$.

$A_2=\{2\},\ A_3=\{2,3\},A_4=A_3,A_5=\{2,3,5\},...$

I assume it is reasonable to consider the set $\bigcup_{j \geq 2} A_j$ as the limit of $A_n$ (if there is discussion about $n \geq 2$ vs. $n \geq 1$, please post that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3313045/678038)),

How can I plug this $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \{2,3,5,...\}$ into the following formula to get the limit infimum and limit supremum of the sequence $(A_n)_{n=2}^\infty$?

${\displaystyle\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j}$

${\displaystyle \limsup _{n\rightarrow \infty }A_{n}=\bigcap _{n\geq 1}\bigcup _{j\geq n}A_{j}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n\in\mathbb N$. Then $\bigcap_{j\geqslant n}A_j=A_n$ (since the sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is increasing) and therefore$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n\geqslant1}\bigcap_{j\geqslant n}A_j=\bigcup_{n\geqslant1}A_n=\{\text{prime numbers}\}.$$On the other hand, $\bigcup_{j\geqslant n}A_j=\{\text{prime numbers}\}$ and therefore$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n\geqslant1}\bigcup_{j\geqslant n}A_j=\bigcap_{n\geqslant1}\{\text{prime numbers}\}=\{\text{prime numbers}\}.$$So,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\{\text{prime numbers}\}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Is $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ increasing or nondecreasing?

Comment: To me, increasing and nondecreasing mean the same thing. If I have to del with a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that$$A_1\varsubsetneq A_2\varsubsetneq A_3\varsubsetneq\cdots,$$then I say that the sequence is *strictly* increasing.