# Can anyone give an simple example of a sequence of sets whose limit infimum is not equal to limit supremum?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

with [José Carlos Santos's help](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3313095/678038), I realized that the limit infimum and limit supremum of primes sequence are equal to the prime numbers $\mathbb{P}$.

In this simple case, or other similar simple case, can anyone give an simple example of a sequence of sets whose limit infimum is not equal to limit supremum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0\}, \{1\}, \ldots $$

The limit inferior contains every element that is present at every step of the sequence from some point onwards. There *is no such element*, so the liminf is $\varnothing$.

The limit superior contains every element that are in infinitely many steps of the sequence. That is $\{0,1\}$.